# ¿Cómo solucionar error al importar una base de conocimiento en genexus?

Tags: java, genexus

Tengo una kb en genexus server y estoy tratando de importarlo desde **knowledge Base from genexus server** estoy usando la **version 16 de genexus** y he ingresado las credenciales y al darle crear me lanza un error de memoria, he revisado en el administrador de tareas y tengo bastante memoria apenas estoy usando el 30 % de 8 gigas de memoria, no sé qué hacer ahora aquí dejo el error por si alguien pueda ayudarme

```
error: GeneXus Server: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
```

Failed: Create Knowledge Base

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En este caso, parece que el 'System.OutOfMemoryException' se da en el servidor donde tienes instalado GXServer, no en el cliente. Deberías tratar de ver este error más específicamente activando el log como indica el siguiente documento: https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?26787,GeneXus+Server+Troubleshooting